# After Update Trigger to update parent status when child status is updated

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

I have a requirement to update parent status when child status is updated.
Service  is a child object and subscription is a parent object.Service has a self lookup.If child services status is updated then subscription status need to be updated.

**Trigger Code**

```
SubscriptionCustomTriggerHandler handler = new SubscriptionCustomTriggerHandler();

      //after insert, update logic
        if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){  
            handler.UpdateSubscriptionStatus(Trigger.new,Trigger.old,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
```

**Handler Class**

```
public class SubscriptionCustomTriggerHandler {

public void UpdateSubscriptionStatus(csord__Service__c[] newServices,csord__Service__c[] oldServices,Map<ID, csord__Service__c> newServicesMap,Map<ID, csord__Service__c> oldServicesMap){

    List<csord__Subscription__c> subslist = new List<csord__Subscription__c>();
    set<Id> servSet = new  set<Id>();  
    set<Id> subSet = new  set<Id>();  
    System.debug('newServices:'+newServices); 
    for(csord__Service__c service: newServices){
        servSet.add(service.id);
        subSet.add(service.csord__Subscription__c);
    }

    subslist = [select id, Name, csord__Status__c, csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c, (SELECT id, csord__Status__c, csord__Subscription__c,csord__Subscription__r.csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c from csord__Services__r serv) From csord__Subscription__c Where Id IN:subSet];
    System.debug('subslist&&&'+subslist); 
    Map<Id, List<csord__Service__c>> subsMap = new Map<Id, List<csord__Service__c>>();  
    for(csord__Subscription__c sub: subslist) {
        for(csord__Service__c serv : sub.csord__Services__r){
            System.debug('serv@@@'+serv); 
            List<csord__Service__c> servList = new List<csord__Service__c>();
            servList.add(serv);

            if(serv.csord__Subscription__r.csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c == null){

                if(subsMap!=null && subsMap.containsKey(serv.csord__Subscription__c))
                {
                    servList.addAll(subsMap.get(serv.csord__Subscription__c));
                }
                //subsMap.put(sub.id,servList);
            }   

            else if(subsMap!=null && subsMap.containsKey(serv.csord__Subscription__r.csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c)){
                {   
                    serv =  [select id, csord__Status__c, csord__Subscription__c,csord__Subscription__r.csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c from csord__Service__c  where Id IN:servSet AND csord__Subscription__r.csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c != NULL];
                    servList.addAll(subsMap.get(serv.csord__Subscription__r.csordtelcoa__Replaced_Subscription__c ));
                }
            }
            subsMap.put(sub.id,servList);
        }
        System.debug('subsMap'+subsMap);
        Integer countInProgress = 0;
        Integer cancellationInProgress = 0;
        Integer Failed = 0;
        Integer connected = 0;
        Integer Disconnected = 0;
        Integer cancelled = 0;

        for(csord__Service__c service: subsMap.get(sub.id)){
            //for Any child service status is In Progress or Cancellation In Progress
            if(service.csord__Status__c == 'In Progress'|| service.csord__Status__c == 'Cancellation In Progress'){
                sub.csord__Status__c = 'In Progress';
            }

            //for All child services status
            if (service.csord__Status__c == 'Cancellation In Progress')
                cancellationInProgress = cancellationInProgress +1;
            else if (service.csord__Status__c == 'Failed')
                Failed = Failed +1;
            else if (service.csord__Status__c == 'Connected')
                Connected = Connected +1;
            else if (service.csord__Status__c == 'Disconnected')
                Disconnected = Disconnected +1;
            else if (service.csord__Status__c == 'Cancelled')
                Cancelled = Cancelled +1;
        }  
        if(subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== cancellationInProgress) 
            sub.csord__Status__c = 'Cancellation In Progress';
        else if(subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Failed) 
            sub.csord__Status__c = 'Failed';
        else if(subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Connected || subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Disconnected || subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Cancelled)
            sub.csord__Status__c = 'Active';
        else if(subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Disconnected || subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Cancelled)
            sub.csord__Status__c = 'Inactive';
        else if(subsMap.get(sub.id).size()== Cancelled)
            sub.csord__Status__c = 'Cancelled';

    } 
    update subslist;
}
}
```

**But when I change service status subscription status is not being updated.**

Comment: are you sure this is triggered on update? how does your trigger look like?

Comment: Yes its a trigger handler

Comment: the question is, is your trigger including before/after update listeners?

Comment: after update trigger

Comment: does your trigger look like this: `trigger myServiceTrigger on csord__Service__c (before update) {`

Comment: Are you sure that the `sub` fields  values are being set in your second loop?  You need to include some `debug` statements in that loop to confirm that the code is executing as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Trigger is listening the right events:

```
trigger myServiceTrigger on csord__Service__c (before update, after update) {
```

Comment: I have given after update